# ActiveX in CPropertyPage can't be used by keyboard

Tags: activex

in my sample project (c++ vs10) i placed an ActiveX control in an Dialog (used as PropertyPage). The Dialog is connected to a CPropertyPage derived class called CTestPage. If i open a PropertySheet with DoModal, where the CTestPage is added, the ActiveX control appears, but i cant handle it by keyboard. If i click the ActiveX control (e.g. Calendar Control 8.0) the control receives the click and works fine. But no keyboard stroke is handled by the control. I tested ten different ActiveX controls on my developer machine -> always the same behavior. 
If i place the ActiveX control in a normal Dialog everything works fine.

Any hints what i do wrong?

Thanks a lot
heribert

PS. Yes, AfxEnableControlContainer is called in InitInstance.

Comment: Have you tried using Spy++ to see who is eating the keyboard messages?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Now i found the problem. See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

A PropertyPage sends WM_GETDLGCODE to every control to check out, which keyboard input can be handled by the control.
All the ActiveX controls i have tested results with 0 as answer on the request! Cool, so no one will receive any keyboard input.
The ActiveX Control i will use is written by me in c#. The ActiveX layer is needed to offer the complex c# control to c++. 
But the underlying complex c# control returns with a 0 on a WM_GETDLGCODE message, too. 
So i subclassed the c# control like the following code and now it works fine!!

```
internal class SubclassedComplexControl : ComplexControl
{
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand,
     Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
     protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
     {
        const int WM_GETDLGCODE = 0x0087;
        const int DLGC_WANTARROWS = 0x0001;
        const int DLGC_WANTALLKEYS = 0x0004;
        const int DLGC_WANTCHARS = 0x0080;
        const int VK_ESCAPE = 0x1B;
        const int VK_RETURN = 0x0D;


        if (m.Msg == WM_GETDLGCODE)
        {
            if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == VK_RETURN || m.WParam.ToInt32() == VK_ESCAPE)
                m.Result = (IntPtr) DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
            else
                m.Result = (IntPtr)(DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTCHARS);
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
     }
 }
```